# Count distinct values of a given column for a number of CSV files

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to read a number of CSV files. They all have in common a certain column, say `'b'`. For each file, I'd like to count distinct `b`.

#### Example

As an example, let's assume I have 10 files. Each file has 5 columns (`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`) and many rows.

How can I get a summary table that shows how many distinct values of `b` per file?

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n = 1000
columns = list('abcde')
np.random.seed(0)
for i in range(10):
    filename = f'file_{i:02d}.csv'
    pd.DataFrame(
        np.random.randint(0, 1000, (n, len(columns))),
        columns=columns,
    ).to_csv(filename, index=False)
```

I would like to get a Pandas DataFrame like

```
filename    count
file_00.csv 10
file_01.csv 3
...
```

Comment: Please check out this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and fix your question accordingly.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. It is not possible to provide a specific answer without you providing sufficient information to understand your problem. Please see: [Why is Can someone help me? not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)  for more details.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Your edit is definitely an improvement, but now this looks like a trivial duplicate. Please search before asking.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from glob import glob

filenames = glob('file_??.csv')
df = pd.Series({
    filename: (~pd.read_csv(filename).duplicated(['b'])).sum()
    for filename in filenames
}).to_frame('count').rename_axis(index='filename')

>>> df
             count
filename          
file_01.csv    645
file_00.csv    613
file_02.csv    617
file_03.csv    626
file_04.csv    623
file_05.csv    644
file_06.csv    615
file_07.csv    628
file_08.csv    645
file_09.csv    636
```

**Bonus: storing rows with each first distinct `b` -**

If the columns are compatible, you can also store the first rows with distinct `b` for each file:

```py
df = pd.concat([
    pd.read_csv(filename).drop_duplicates(['b'])
    for filename in filenames
], keys=filenames)

>>> df
                   a    b    c    d    e
file_01.csv 0    689  191  884  615  649
            1     24   68  794  820  107
            2    566  469  718  157  897
            3    206  256  527  417  672
            4    765  755  741  197  926
...              ...  ...  ...  ...  ...
file_09.csv 986  626  622  224  726  274
            988  329  900  577   26  221
            990   47  800  369  567   11
            998  602  198  165  217  682
            999  564  982  890  126  450

[6292 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ... But the distinct should be for each file alone and on specific columns . Didn't see any remark about it

Comment: I had missed that. Corrected. Also modified your question to include a MRE and voted to reopen.